# How to remove only zero digit from python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to remove `0` only from my list:

```py
>>> mylist = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]
```

All of them missing False items

```py
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != 0, mylist))
[1, None, 2, 1]  # missing False

>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != 0 and x is not type(int), mylist))
[1, None, 2, 1] # missing False

>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != 0 and x is not type(False), mylist))
[1, None, 2, 1]

>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != 0 and x is not False, mylist))
[1, None, 2, 1]
```

Desired output:

```
[1, None, 2, False, 1]
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: because False is a boolean version of 0

Comment: `False` *is* 0 in Python. It's literally an integer with value 0. `bool` is an `int` subclass.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of `True + True = 2`  and `True - False`. Sure they are just Boolean representation. Now I come here to ask better solution for the case above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python [`bool`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/bool.html#boolean-objects) is a subclass of `int` and `False` is analogous to 0. Hence compare by equality does not yield desired output.

You can use (**Note this is least preferred and you ideally should not use**):

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x is not 0, mylist))
[1, None, 2, False, 1]
```

**What you should use:**

An identity check may not work out in all cases as discussed in comments. A more feasible way would be to use equality check with type check as:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x != 0 or isinstance(x, bool), mylist))
[1, None, 2, False, 1]
```

Personally, not a fan of `filter` and `lambda`, I would use a list-comprehension which proves faster:

```
>>> [x for x in mylist if x != 0 or isinstance(x, bool)]
[1, None, 2, False, 1]
```

Comment: This code assumes there will only ever be one `0` object. This assumption is wrong. For example, on current CPython, and I believe on any 3.x version of CPython, `pow(2, 128, 2**128) == 0`, but `pow(2, 128, 2**128) is not 0`. [Filtering a list with that 0 in it using this code produces a list that still has a 0 in it.](https://ideone.com/wgH0os)

Comment: (2.x produces the same results for those comparisons, but on 2.x, the `pow` produces `0L`.)

Comment: An identity check against `0` is fundamentally wrong here. An identity check against `False` or a type check against `int` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @user2357112, fair point, though I don't think OP has cases that my initial code fails; but a good point to note.

Comment: Do not rely on the implementation detail of the small int cache. The first solution is wrong

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, already added other ways to do the same. The first solution is working atleast in the context of OP. That's why it is still in the answer.

Comment: And yet you keep a fundamentally flawed answer for the world to see... Please don't encourage people to incorrectly rely on identity comparisons when they should not

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, agree to it. Amended the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for data type of `x` also and then use `!=` operator.

```
# works for integer 0
[x for x in mylist if type(x) != int or x != 0] 
# works for float 0.0 as well
[x for x in mylist if (type(x) != int and type(x) != float) or x != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

type `bool` is a sub type of `int`, so `False` translates to `0`. I think an solution is to stringify the number and filter it. There are also good and better answers given here:

```
list(filter(lambda x: str(x) != '0', mylist))
```

Answer (score -1):

The `x is not 0` approach works, but is probably not optimal. There speed enhancements by using a `list comprehension` instead of using calls to `list()` and to `filter()`.

Running this in a Jupyter notebook and taking advantage of the builtin `%timeit` magic to see how quickly each of these can return the result.

```
mylist = [0, 1, None, 2, False, 1, 0]
```

**Using list() and filter()**

```
%timeit list(filter(lambda x: x is not 0, mylist))
**1.12 µs** ± 17.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

**Using a list comprehsion**

```
%timeit [i for i in mylist if i is not 0]
**411 ns** ± 8.42 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

We see that the list comprehension technique is significantly faster.

Comment: It is wrong to compare integers by identity when you mean equality